# Stampacchia's theorem (proof in Brezis's book)

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, riesz-representation-theorem

I was studying the proof of Stampacchia's theorem from Haim Brezis's book, attached the theorem with the proof:

> **Theorem:** Assume that $a(u,v)$ is a continuous coercive bilinear form on $H$. Let $K\subseteq H$ be a nonempty closed and convex subset.
> Then, given any $\phi\in H^{\star}$, there exists a unique element
> $u\in K$ such that
> \begin{equation} 
>      a(u,v-u) \geq \langle\phi,v-u\rangle\quad \forall v\in K
>  \end{equation}
> Moreover, if $a$ is symmetric, then $u$ is characterized by the property:
> \begin{equation*}
>             u\in K\text{ and }\frac{1}{2}a(u,v)-\langle\phi , u\rangle = \min_{v\in K}\{a(v,v)/2 - \langle\phi , u\rangle\}
>         \end{equation*}

**I can't understand how the same $ u \in K $ fulfills both properties, is it the same? and where in the demo do I see that the u element of the first property is used for the second. As I see in the demonstration, nothing ensures that the element $ u $ that fulfills the first property, when adding the new hypotheses, is the same that fulfills the second property**

*The proof is:* (I add a few steps to make it easier to read):

By the Riesz-Fréchet representation theorem, for $\phi\in H^{\star}$ exists $f\in H$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    \langle\phi,v\rangle = (f,v)    \quad   \forall v\in H
\end{equation*}
On the other hand, taking $u\in H$, we have the function $v\mapsto a(u,v)$ a continuous linear function on $H$. Using again the Riesz-Fréchet representation theorem, there is a single representative in $H$, denoted by $Au$, such that:
\begin{equation}
    \label{BilinealStampacchia}
    a(u,v) = (Au,v)     \quad   \forall v\in H
\end{equation}

1. Let's see next that $u\mapsto Au$ is a continuous linear function on $H$: Note that $Au\in H$, then considering $v = Au$ on $a(u,v) = (Au,v)     \quad   \forall v\in H$, we have
   \begin{eqnarray}
       a(u,Au) = (Au,Au) = |Au|^{2}
   \end{eqnarray}
   and since $a$ is continuous we limit obtaining
   \begin{equation*}
       \begin{array}{rrcl}
                       &   |Au| = \sqrt{a(u,Au)}       & \leq &    \sqrt{C|u||Au|} \quad\forall u\in H\\
           \Rightarrow &   \dfrac{|Au|}{\sqrt{|Au|}}   & \leq &    \sqrt{C|u|}     \quad\forall u\in H\\
           \Rightarrow &   \sqrt{|Au|}                 & \leq &    \sqrt{C|u|}     \quad\forall u\in H\\
           \Rightarrow &   |Au|                        & \leq &    C|u|            \quad\forall u\in H\\
       \end{array}
   \end{equation*}
2. Let's see what $(Au,u) \geq C'|u|^{2}$: We know that $a(u,v) = (Au, v)$ for all $v\in H$, in particular if we consider $u \in H$ we have to
   \begin{equation*}
       a(u,u) = (Au,u) \geq C'|u|^{2}\quad\forall u\in H
   \end{equation*}

Let's see what exists $u\in K$ such that $(Au,v-u) \geq (f,v-u)$ for all $v\in K$: Note that the desired is equivalent to:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{rrcl}
    \Leftrightarrow &      (Au,v-u)  & \geq &      (f,v-u)\\
    \Leftrightarrow &      0         & \geq &      (f,v-u)-(Au,v-u)\\
    \Leftrightarrow &      0         & \geq &      (f-Au,v-u)\\
    \Leftrightarrow &      0         & \geq &      \rho(f-Au,v-u)\\
    \Leftrightarrow &      0         & \geq &      (\rho f-\rho Au,v-u)\\
    \Leftrightarrow &      0         & \geq &      (\rho f-\rho Au+u-u,v-u)     \quad\forall v\in K\\
    \Leftrightarrow &      u         & =    &       P_{K}(\rho f-\rho Au+u)     
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
Let $S(v):= P_{K}(\rho f - \rho Av+v)$, choosing some $\rho>0$, $S$ is a strict contraction and we can use the
*Fixed Point Theorem (Banach)*. Then, how $P_{K}$ does not increase distances (that is, it is Lipschitz with constant $ 1 $), then:
\begin{eqnarray*}
|S(v_{1}) - S(v_{2})| \leq |(v_{1}-v_{2}) - \rho(Av_{1}-Av_{2})|
\end{eqnarray*}
So we can finally get a bound using the properties (1) and (2) tested for $A$
\begin{eqnarray*}
|S(v_{1}) - S(v_{2})|^{2}   & = &   S(v_{1})^{2} - 2S(v_{1})S(v_{2}) + S(v_{2})\\
                            & = &   |v_{1}-v_{2}|^{2} +\rho^{2}|Av_{1}-Av_{2}|^{2} - 2\rho(Av_{1}-Av_{2},v_{1}-v_{2})\\
                           &\leq&   |v_{1}-v_{2}|^{2}\cdot(1-2\rho C'+\rho^{2} C)
\end{eqnarray*}
and finally, choosing $\rho$ such that $0<\rho <\frac{2C'}{C^{2}}$, we have to $S$ has a single fixed point, with which we can conclude that
\begin{equation*}
S(u):= P_{K}(\rho f - \rho Au+u) = u
\end{equation*}
equivalent to:
\begin{equation*}
a(u,v-u) \geq \langle\phi , v-u\rangle\ \forall v\in K
\end{equation*}

To prove the second property of the theorem, we now assume that $a(u,v) $ is symmetric, then $a(u,v) $ defines a new dot product over $H$ and thus defines a Hilbertian norm $\sqrt{a(u,u)} $ which turns out to be equivalent to the original norm of $H$. Since the norms are equivalent then $H$ remains a Hilbert space with the norm $\sqrt{a (u,u)}$. Using the *Riesz-Fréchet representation theorem*, for $\phi\in H^{\star} $ there is a single representative $g\in H$ such that

\begin{equation*}
\langle\phi,v\rangle = a(g,v)   \quad   v\in H
\end{equation*}
Now let's find some $u\in K$ such that
\begin{equation*}
a(g-u,v-u)\leq0\quad\forall v\in K
\end{equation*}
The $u$ we are looking for is simply the projection of $g$ onto $K$ for the inner product $a(\cdot,\cdot)$. By the *projection theorem on closed convexes* there is a unique $u\in K$ such that it reaches
\begin{equation*}
\min_{v\in K}\sqrt{a(g-v,v-v)}
\end{equation*}
so it is enough to minimize the function over $K$
\begin{eqnarray*}
v   \mapsto     a(g-v,g-v)      & = &   a(v,v)-2a(g,v)+a(g,g)\\
                                & = &   a(v,v)-2\langle\phi,v\rangle+a(g,g)
\end{eqnarray*}
or equivalently the function
\begin{equation*}
v\mapsto\frac{1}{2}a(v,v)-\langle\phi,v\rangle
\end{equation*}

Comment: What exactly is your question/until when do you follow the proof?

Comment: In the second property, I don't see that the $u$ element exactly complies with the first property, I don't see anything that indicates this in the proof, as I understand it could be a different element in both properties

Comment: Why would it not comply with the first property? The second property is *in addition* to the first one. Can you see that $a(g-u,v-u)\leq0\quad\forall v\in K$ is precisely the first property in the scenario where $a$ induces a new dot product on $H$?

Answer (score 1):

From the first part of the theorem we have $$a(u,v-u)\geq \langle \phi,v-u\rangle, $$ and then $$a(u,v)-\langle \phi,v\rangle\geq a(u,u)-\langle \phi,u\rangle.\;\;\;\;\; (*) $$

Also, by bilinearity, coercivity and now symmetry, from $$a(v-u,v-u)\geq \alpha\|v-u\|^2\geq 0 $$ we have
$$\frac{1}{2}a(v,v)\geq a(v,u)-\frac{1}{2}a(u,u).$$

Then, $$\frac{1}{2}a(v,v)-\langle \phi,v\rangle\geq a(v,u)-\frac{1}{2}a(u,u)-\langle \phi,v\rangle,$$ using the inequality (*)
$$\frac{1}{2}a(v,v)-\langle \phi,v\rangle\geq a(u,u)-\langle \phi,u\rangle-\frac{1}{2}a(u,u),$$ and that is it !